# why facebook email is not retrieved?

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

After user accept to sign in with his facebook account, my app callback will be called by facebook, I've noticed that facebook didn't retrieved user email, although in the configuration of omniauth, I've listed email in the permission list like this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, omniauth_app_id, omniauth_app_secret_id,
           :scope => 'email,user_birthday,read_stream', :display => 'popup'
end
```

I am expecting to find email in `request.env['omniauth.auth']['extra']['raw_info']['email']` or `request.env['omniauth.auth']['info']['raw_info']['email']`
But, its not there .. in fact, its not in any attribute within the `request` object!

Any idea ? is it related to my app facebook settings ?

**EDIT**

Here is the call back result from Facebook:

```
puts auth.inspect

#<OmniAuth::AuthHash credentials=#<Hashie::Mash expires=true expires_at=1353164400 token="***"> extra=#<Hashie::Mash raw_info=#<Hashie::Mash first_name="***" id="***" last_name="***" link="***" locale="ar_AR" name="***" timezone=2 updated_time="2012-11-17T13:01:59+0000" username="***" verified=true>> info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash first_name="***" image="***" last_name="***" name="***" nickname="***" urls=#<Hashie::Mash Facebook="***"> verified=true> provider="facebook" uid="***">
```

I have replaced reall data with ***, but, you can see that the email data is missing ..

**EDIT2**

Here is my gems used at Gemfile
    gem 'devise'

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'

gem 'oauth2'
```

Comment: Can you add the callback result to your question?

Comment: We have a similar call and get the email without issue. When I'm back at my computer Ill dig my code out.

Comment: Hey. Sorry. Am away for the weekend but will update my answer when I return on Sunday. S

Comment: thanks, I am starting to think as I dont need their emails, instead I can ask them to provide it ..

Comment: Much nicer grabbing it and better to solve your problem :)

Comment: Thats what I've been trying to do .. but if I could not I still can have facebook users as customers, I hope to resolve this though ..

Comment: Will post a full setup when I have laptop later. Did you have any luck with LinkedIn?

Comment: I didn't try LinkedIn due to lack of time, I've worked on other client side tasks .. still other tasks to do ..

Comment: I think trying linkedin would help a lot. You need to figure out if it's fb or your app. I don't have the outh gem installed. This is the only configuration that really differs from yours. Try and remove that and use omniauth only. The only other configuration difference is my omniauth initialiser. Remove oauth and change your config to what's in my updated answer.

Comment: hey! I found the answer!, please see my answered answer, I really appreciate your help& support as well, thanks very much simon

Comment: Ok, glad to hear it and glad to have helped. S

Comment: Just wondering if you could give me a +1 for the comments / attempted answer :)

Comment: Sure! in fact, you have motivated me to keep looking, as I thought to ask their email, thanks very much simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found it! Here is what facebook says [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/463026327071975/summary?save=1)

> By default, calling FB.login will attempt to authenticate the user
>   with only the basic permissions. If you want one or more additional
>   permissions, call FB.login with an option object, and set the scope
>   parameter with a comma-separated list of the permissions you wish to
>   request from the user.

So, I have to add 'email' like this:

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

Thanks very much for all people who tried to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to have an facebook account without confirm the email. In this case, the `request.env['omniauth.auth']['info']` has no `'email'` key.

Answer (score 1):

How about fetching it from the `info` hash?

```
request.env['omniauth.auth']['info']['email']
```

I think that it is what [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) recomends in the Auth Hash section

Answer (score 1):

We use devise and omniauth for facebook - following the following railscast. I don't know if you can adapt but we have successfully pulled the email and some other info. from the callback.

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Our controller action looks like this (condensed):

```
  def create  
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]  
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])  
    if authentication  
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)  
    elsif current_user  
      current_user.authentications.create(:provider => omniauth ['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])  
      redirect_to authentications_url  
    else
      user = User.new
      user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      if user.save
        sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
      else   
        session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
       end
    end  
  end
```

User.apply_omniauth:

```
   def apply_omniauth(omniauth)  
     authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid']) 
   end
```

We get the email, as advise by someone else, using this:

```
 @omniauth_email = session[:omniauth][:info][:email]
```

I hope this helps, I know it's not quiet what you're looking for.

-- edit --

My initialiser is different to yours. Try removing all that xs stuff and use something like this:

```
 Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do  
  provider :facebook, 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx'  
 ...
 end
```

Comment: Thanks, but, at my callback, I've checked request.env["omniauth.auth"], in any of its attributes inside, there is no email sent from facebook, shall I look in my facebook application ?

Comment: If you're doing the same as that, it must be your application settings. I can check what we've got a little later for you.

Comment: What kind of app in facebook have you created? Can you send a screen shot of settings perhaps? Also, have you tried another provider that sends the email, like Linkedin? Might be worth giving that a try to narrow down whether it's your application, settings or other. S

Comment: I have added a screen shot for basic/ permissions/ advanced settings for my app above, I hope you can check it .. I will check for another provider to see, I will check Twitter ..

Comment: hello simon, did you see the attached screenshot ? can you help please

Comment: Oh sorry! I did reply but can't have pushed add comment. Your settings are the same as mine and I can't see anything wrong from here. Have you tried another provider, like LinkedIn? Just for a test. Also, which gem and version are you using?? S

Comment: Its ok :-) I will try to use Linkedln, and I will send you gems I am using for this when I come back home .. thanks simon by the way, is it ok to leave User and Friends permissions empty ?

Comment: Hey, let me know later. I had some issues with devise and omniauth. My user and friends permissions are empty too. Think that's ok.

Comment: When you have time, please see EDIT2 above to see my gems