# request.env['omniauth.auth']["info"]["email "] returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have a rails application and I am using omniAuth to authorise Facebook login and my problem is that Facebook did not return emails.

Here is the data:

```
 ruby '2.1.7'
 Graph API V2.5
```

I have both gems'omniauth'and'omniauth-facebook'installed. is there a specific gem version for 'omniauth' and 'omniauth-facebook' that I should install ?

In my config.omniauth I added

```
info_fields: 'email
```

but unfortunately I am still facing the same issue.

I tried these below solutions but none of them worked for me

[why facebook email is not retrieved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427642/why-facebook-email-is-not-retrieved)

I added as well the email as well when calling this function

```
 FB.api('/me?fields=name, email', function(response) {
      console.log(response);
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.email + '!';
    });
```

FYI: I am testing the application with real users whom address emails were verified and when connecting to Facebook I am entering the address email not the phone number.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check koala gem
you can specify the version and fields you want to return.

Comment: Sorry,  didn't get what you mean

Comment: Thanks @James Dela Cruz for the hint. I made it work by using graph API email= user_graph.get_object("me", :fields=>"email, name")["email"]

Comment: nice you can add also version


`Koala.config.api_version = "v2.0"`
`@graph.get_object("me", {}, api_version: "v2.0")`